# Count likes of the latest date per user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **"article_likes"** of **users** and whether they like or dislike the article. With every **like/dislike** the **datetime** is saved and the **id** of the article. The **like/dislike** is saved as a bool in the "status" column.

```
id     article_id     user_id     like_date              status
1      8              2           2014-11-03 21:30:33    1
2      8              2           2014-11-03 21:31:00    0
3      8              3           2014-11-03 22:30:59    1
4      9              6           2014-11-03 22:36:25    1
5      9              2           2014-11-03 23:19:46    1
```

I like to get the amount of likes an article has. So only the status of the most recent date is valid for the count.

So the desired **result** would be:

```
article_id     amount_likes
8              1
9              2
```

I want to get the result per article id, so not all at once.

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: `GROUP BY DATE(like_date)`?

Comment: Can't you save dislike as `-1` and sum it up?

Comment: What do you mean latest date? the latest day per article or latest date overall?

Comment: I tried it with -1 instead of 0 and sum it up and it worked. Thanks! After the answer below I changed it to zeros again, because I think it looks cleaner. But it uses the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem :)

```
SELECT article_id, SUM(IF(status = 1, 1, -1)) AS amount_likes FROM article_likes
GROUP BY article_id
```

If you store dislikes as -1 then:

```
SELECT article_id, SUM(status) AS amount_likes FROM article_likes
GROUP BY article_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `article_id`,COUNT(`user_id`) AS amount_likes FROM `links`
WHERE `status`='1' GROUP BY DATE(`like_date`), `user_id`;
```

Fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b7bb6/4

Hope it helps

Comment: Doesn't meet: "So only the status of the most recent date is valid for the count"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT article_id, COUNT(IF(
                           SELECT CASE 
                                  WHEN status=1 THEN 'true' 
                                  ELSE 'false'
                                  END),
                                 'true','false'
                           )
                         )
FROM article_likes
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY article_id
```